# Microsoft Edge won't open the web site until opens the Fiddler

Tags: html, microsoft-edge, fiddler

When I put the website url in the Microsoft Edge browser address bar, and press
"Enter", nothing happened, the webpage does not show. Open the developers tool menu by pressing F12, go to the "Network" tab, there is no content at all. Note: I have this website's source code and hosted in a server. This problem does not occur to any other websites except this website.

However, if I open the Fiddler, and do the same thing, the webpage shows with no issue.

There is no problems in google chrome, internet explorer, and Firefox.

I have struggle with this for a couple of days, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you installed the January 8, 2019—KB4480966 (OS Build 17134.523) or January 15, 2019—KB4480976 (OS Build 17134.556) updates? If yes than it can be possible that this update cause this issue with your site. Ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4480966/windows-10-update-kb4480966 and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4480976/windows-10-update-kb4480976 Let us know, If you had installed these updates. We will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, yes, from my windows update history, there is an update KB4480966 installed on 9th of January, another update KB4480976 is not installed.

Comment: If you visit those 2 links than in known issues section, you can find that MS Edge has some issues with loading the pages in it. New update got launched on February 12, 2019—KB4487017 (OS Build 17134.590). which claims that it resolves this issue. I suggest you to try to install that update and again try to check for the issue to check whether it solved or not. Ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4487017/windows-10-update-kb4487017

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT thank you very much. The new update KB4487017 solved my problem, now Microsoft edge has no issue to open this webpage.

Comment: From your last comment, I can see that installing the KB4487017 solved your issue. So I had posted the solution as an answer. I suggest you to mark that answer as an accepted answer for this question may help other community members in similar issues in future. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you visit those 2 links than in known issues section, you can find that MS Edge has some issues with loading the pages in it.

[image]

New update got launched on February 12, 2019—KB4487017 (OS Build 17134.590). which claims that it resolves this issue. I suggest you to try to install that update and again try to check for the issue to check whether it solved or not.

Ref: [February 12, 2019—KB4487017 (OS Build 17134.590)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4487017/windows-10-update-kb4487017)